# Android How do I distinguish shortcut and applicaion icon to start activity

Tags: android

I have An Application, I create a `shortcut` when I start my app。I click the shortcut and open an new activity  ,then I press `home key` take the activity background ,then  I click the application's icon(not shortcut's), the shortcut's activity is open,I want open Applicaiton's Main activity ,what should I do?

Comment: i'm trying to guess what you mean: by "shortcut" you mean the icon on the home screen while by "not shortcut" you mean the one in the app drawer? if so, i'm not aware of any way to distinguish between those two types of app start but perhaps someone else does... i would also edit the question to clarify what you mean

Comment: thank you ,when the app install ,on the home screen will generate an app icon, the 'shortcut' is the app generate another icon for do other things ,so on home screen,there have two icons ,one is call "ICON" ,the ohter call "shortcut",

Answer (score 0):

You may put a small mark on shortcut created.A code sample will be

```
Bitmap shortcutIcon2 = Util.confleteBitmap((UtilityClass.StringToBitMap(IconShortcut), BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.shortcut_mark));
```

*this puts a shortcutmark image on bottom of shortcut created*